# Missing right parenthesis?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
    PID Int Not Null,
    FirstName Varchar2(15) Not Null,
    LastName Varchar2(15) Not Null,
    Email Varchar2(50) Not Null,
    Type Varchar2(15) Not Null Default Customer,
    Primary Key(PID)
);
```

I`m getting the following error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type` is a reserved word in SQL (or at least, in Oracle's flavor of it). You could either escape it using double quotes (`"`):

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    PID Int Not Null,
    FirstName Varchar2(15) Not Null,
    LastName Varchar2(15) Not Null,
    Email Varchar2(50) Not Null,
    "Type" Varchar2(15) Default 'Customer' Not Null,
    Primary Key(PID)
);
```

Or just use a name that isn't a reserved word, such as `person_type`:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    PID Int Not Null,
    FirstName Varchar2(15) Not Null,
    LastName Varchar2(15) Not Null,
    Email Varchar2(50) Not Null,
    Person_Type Varchar2(15)  Default 'Customer' Not Null,
    Primary Key(PID)
);
```

EDIT:
As @a_horse_with_no_name commented, the default value "Customer" is a string literal, so it has to be enclosed with single quotes (`'`).

EDIT2:
The default value clause should come before the `not null` clause.

Comment: Also: `Default Customer` has to be `Default 'Customer'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good catch. I've edited this in to my answer.

Comment: I made all the modifications you mentioned, but it`s still giving me the same error, missing right parenthesis.

Comment: @me.user My bad - missed another problem. See my edited answer.